# Is controlled infinite recursion in asynchronous functions harmful?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

So I obviously know infinite loops are bad and can cause stack overflow, but in the following case I am using an asynchronous function to get the next date, and sleeping my functioning until the time i want it to execute. Which means it will only run once per day, at 12am to be exact and will be sleep-ed until the next day.

```
async def foo():
  sleep_until = await get_time()  # gets time until 12am tomorrow
  await asyncio.sleep(sleep_until)

  # execute whatever my task is here

  await foo()
```

While it executes fine and works, I have a few unanswered questions being a novice programmer.

1. Can this block of code cause memory leaks?
2. Does the previous iteration ever ends? Or does it continue to exist forever until the program crashes or is stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this on your own using a simple program and a short sleep timer. **Yes**, it does cause the stack to overflow -

```py
# bug.py

from asyncio import run, sleep
from datetime import datetime

async def foo():
  print(datetime.now())
  await sleep(.0001)
  await foo()         # recursion causes overflow

run(foo())
```

The obvious fix in this situation is to use `while` instead of recursion -

```py
# fix.py

from asyncio import run, sleep
from datetime import datetime

async def forever(func, delay):
  while True:
    await func()
    await sleep(delay)

async def foo():
  print(datetime.now()) 

run(forever(foo, .0001))  # no overflow
```

Or thinking outside the realm of python, you may want to consider [crontab(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5).